# How do you practice outwardly giving?

Tags: dana

Since most of you have neither much chances to practicing generosity toward the Sangha and aside probably not easy finding individual people worthy of gifts, how do you, living in outer lands, try to practice such to have a basement for further training toward path?

Comment: Are you asking only about the Sangha? Perhaps yes, because you regard the Sangha as the only base one can have for further training?

Answer (score 1):

My person thought, aside of encouraging to help each other to do merits also in very gross form, to give some tips of what might be conductive for getting and staying in contact with good people and perform also some merits by things even if far off:

That you may have admirable people in your real of living near, at least internet:

Look that you can provide space, connection, accounts... without strings, but given by your effort and strength, keeping them away from getting bond by contracts and duties.

There are (a devoted Upasaka found out and informed) today even possibilities to fill up such as cell-phone credits if you can manage that people living on alms can access devices and maintain them.

If you have room, space... try to let them know that they are always welcome. Also if having joy in giving alms-food, medicine and clothes, let it be known and try to maintain places where it could touch those who do not ask or write wish lists.

My person encourages you not only to share ways but also to share the merits, because otherwise, how many theoretical input you may gain, the Gems would not prosper for one who makes no scarifies at first place. One is wise if being that selfish in this way and does not much doubt in it's benefit.

Don't act like a consumer or even a trader. When just giving out of owning something or just to get something later back of which is perceivable, such wouldn't make you glad to an extend that you gain real joy with your self and the found freedom and richness you actually would have all the time.

Try it, and stick firm to precepts while doing so, or preparing for such, since without it would not last that long, just like a sort holiday with a lot of debts when returning home again.

May a lot of rejoice-worthy and for you inspiring hints and tips follow and it's always best not only to share ones merits as much as possible but to also invite others to join this or that undertaking.

Mudita

*(Note that this is given only for trade, exchange, stacks and entertainment that nourishes your secure way out of the bond where trapped)*

Answer (score 0):

Many monasteries with foundations/trusts which accept and manage money/gifts for Sangha do take checks and other forms of electronic fund transfer. And they often publish "wish list" which could be purchased and shipped directly from Amazon.